# Why does HasMany().WithMany() generates wrong (?) schema

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm mapping my model code-first with fluent API for schema generation. Point of interest being

```
public class RoleMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Role>
{
    public RoleMapping()
    {
        // ...
        this.HasMany(r => r.Permissions).WithMany();
    }
}
```

I would expect Roles table, Perimssions table and intermediate table. However unless I add a Roles navigation property do the Permission class I'm getting only two tables generated:

```
CREATE TABLE [Roles](
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Name] [nvarchar](max) NULL )
GO

CREATE TABLE [Permissions](
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Role_Id] [int] NULL)
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Permissions]  WITH CHECK 
ADD CONSTRAINT [Role_Permissions] FOREIGN KEY([Role_Id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Roles] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Permissions] CHECK CONSTRAINT [Role_Permissions]
GO
```

Why does it work like that?

Comment: What do you think is wrong with this, it looks correct to me

Comment: The third table is missing. This is many to many after all. It seems though I made a mistake elsewhere. Please see my next comment (will post answer later when I'm allowed)

Answer (score 0):

Ah, my mistake.

What I was missing adding the mappings to model builder:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new RoleMapping());
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PermissionMapping());

    // other mapping configurations
}
```